# Alt-click is not selecting edge loops in lInux

Tags: transforms

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: Are you using Linux OS?

Comment: The only time this happened to me was when I was customizing some keyboard shortcuts a while back.  Have you tried 'File -> Load Factory Settings'

Comment: Welcome to SE Toran! It's a little hard to understand what might be wrong from the little information you've provided - could you edit the question and add some info like: Your OS, version of Blender, a screenshot of the whole interface after you try selecting it, etc. You can also double check that your GPU drivers are up to date, and that you downloaded Blender from blender.org and not from one of the linux repositories (these can be unreliable).

Comment: I assume you meant `Alt`+`RMB`?

Comment: Sorry I am running linux mint 17.1 version of blender is the latest version DL off blender.org. And the load factory setting has been done now but would have been nice if you had said save you work first, it wiped 3.5hours worth of work. lol

Comment: @Toran you need to use the right click.

Comment: @Toran sorry you lost 3.5 hours of work, but what were you thinking not saving for 3.5 hours?

Comment: @david just in the zone man, in the zone. will add saving to the zone in the future. I have my select to the left mouse button. it doesn't work

Comment: blender has auto save functionnalities. Is your problem the same with another file? Did factory settings solve the problem?

Comment: no factory setting did not solve the problem it is still not working. I can go into select and select the edge loops from there but just not as a hot key.

Comment: Maybe it's not edge loops (duplicate topology, E or T poles, NGons...). try creating a UV sphere and loop selection.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/are-there-any-special-considerations-for-using-blender-on-linux/24198#24198

Answer (score 13):

Alt key in most Linux window managers doesn't work properly with blender. You can configure it in various window managers, but the easiest solution for me is to shift+alt click. It will select an edge loop, but its in a "additive mode" so it works for selecting 1 edge loop, and continues selecting edge loops as if you are shift selecting multiple items.

Sorry if this text description is confusing, but try shift+alt click on the edge loop and it should achieve what you want.

Comment: In Cinnamon you can go to System Settings > Windows > Behavior. It's the entry called "Special key to move and resize windows".

Comment: Neither ALT-click or SHIFT-alt click works (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Shift+Alt+Click works for me on Ubuntu Mate/XFCE 20.04 without any modifications :)

Answer (score 10):

In most Linux OS's, the window action key is alt which conflics with many Blender shortcuts the most noticable of which is the alt->click edge loop short cut.

It can be harder to fix this problem than some of the other conflicting hotkeys because it isn't actually in the keyboard hotkeys menu.

In most OS's it's in the window resizing settings panel. In the cinnamon and xfce window managers, this is found in the normal settings manager or can also be found by searching for it. In the GNOME window manager, it can be found in the GNOME Tweak Tool under windows.

All you have to do is locate the window action key, or basically a drop down menu that by default has alt in it. Just change this to something like super, or in GNOME, you can change it to disable like I have it.

Answer (score 6):

I just found out (after reading about resetting to defaults) that(in my) Blenderversion 2.76b the edgeloop- selection command does not work when 3- button mouse emulation is enabled. I hope that helps, I was searching like hell! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Blender 2.78c but I'm sure it would be a general thing:

*User Preferences > Input > Shortcut list > 3D View  > Mesh*

1. *Loop Select* (1) Change *Mouse* to *Keyboard*
2. Change shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. *Loop Select* (2) Change *Mouse* to *Keyboard*
4. Change shortcut to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Even though this is not the correct solution, in the end I found it to be the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

This has been up for awhile, but when looking for a correct answer, for me, I found that Tom's answer is correct. In my case, I am using **Arch Linux** with a **xfce** desktop. So to extend on Tom's answer, I found the fix by going to **Settings > Window Manager Tweaks > Accessibility (tab)**: Here there is a drop down *"Key used to grab and move windows"*. I switched it from Alt to Super and the problem was fixed.

Comment: In Linux Mint it's similar: **System Settings > Windows > Behavior** Then disable Alt key from the "special key to move and resize windows" field.

Comment: Above did the trick for me too in Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

Comment: As I came here with the same problem but  KDE - I eventually found the setting for Plasma 5.20 in:
**Windows Management->Window Behavior->Window Actions** and not in shortcuts as I first tought.