# Alt-click is not selecting edge loops on a mac.

Tags: interface, selection-tools

I'm using right click but no joy.

It used to work but something has changed and I can't figure out what.

Comment: This could be related to this bug report that was posted: https://developer.blender.org/T45450

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alt-click is not selecting edge loops why?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24473/alt-click-is-not-selecting-edge-loops-why)

Comment: @cegaton "Alt-click is not selecting edge loops why?" is a question relating to a Linux user and the proposed solution is not applicable in my case.

Comment: Does it work if you revert to factory settings? (*File > Revert to factory settings*)

Comment: I had right click stop working for me on OSX. Has it stopped working completely for any selection, or just for edge loops?

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to do this

You need to go to *edit > preference* under the *Input*. turn off *emulate 3 button mouse*.

or

You need to go to *edit > preference* under the *Keymap* search for *Loop Select* and change it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>